# Are "/register" and "register" routes in node/express the same?

Tags: node.js, html, express

```
app.get("/register", function(req, res) { res.render("register"); });
app.get("register", function(req, res) { res.render("register"); });
```

In href i will provide /register and register. What will be the difference.

Comment: no second one is invalid

Answer (score 3):

```
app.get("register", function ...
```

Is an invalid route, the handler for this route will never get hit. The leading `/` is required.